# Laravel blade prettier formatting but removed the syntax highlighting and snippets

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, prettier

I added `*.blade.php` as html in the `files.associations` to have prettier format for my `blade.php` files but this results to remove the snippets and highlighting needed in the `blade.php` files. I'm using Prettier for my formatting and Laravel Blade Snippets for my highlighting and snippets. Is there any other way to format blade files as html but keep the snippets and highlighting?

With `*.blade.php` in `files.associations`
[image]

without `*.blade.php` in `files.associations`
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. The only thing that works for me was:

- Install this extension: [Laravel Blade](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amirmarmul.laravel-blade-vscode)
- Add in `settings.json`

  ```
    "[blade]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "amirmarmul.laravel-blade-vscode",
      "editor.formatOnSave": true
    }
  ```